# Redirect browser from root folder to same level folder in website

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I have a Nodejs app in my website, it works fine, but in the **same hosting** I have another environment with PHP/Apache in that way:

```
-
|_ /mysite/ app.js _ index
|                 |_ pag01, etc.
|
|_ /www/index.html
```

The app.js is the entry point to the website, but I want to redirect the browser from the app.js/index to the www folder. I can't see a way to redirect with a relative path, like '../www'.
How can I redirect the browser to a 'parallel' folder relative to my root (see screenshot attached)?
I will ask my hosting service for help tomorrow (it's Saturday night and the boys need to sleep), but I'm really curious about it.
Many thanks!

Print
[Print of root folder in host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWWLH.png)

Comment: If you set up vhosts for the 2nd app and assign it a domain name, you could easily redirect to it  using that name with `header('Location: http://www.otherapp.com/');`. If this is local dev, you can make up any vhost domain you want and then map the domain name to your machine's ip in your hosts file.

Comment: Hi, Wesley! thanks for your help! I think your answer is correct, but my hosting limit many server resources, I fix the problem erasing the node app and setting the www folder as default and will reinstall node as a internal service for learning purposes. Thank you for your time and help!